# How does an LL parser evaluate this expression?

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

Considering this expression:

3 + 2 + 2 * 2 = ?

Would it be 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  That's what you'd get in left-to-right evaluation.  An LL parser would build the same parse tree as an LR parser,

```
  +
 / \
3   +
   / \
  2   *
     / \
    2   2
```

and evaluate it as

```
(+ 3 (+ 2 (* 2 2))
```

which is 9, as you'd expect.

What is special about LL parsers is that, for a restricted grammar, they can always proceed left to right with limited look-ahead.  This makes them easy to describe and easy to parse; some Pascal is one of the most common languages that is LL.

You might have a look at the Wiki article on [leftmost derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees).